# How To Resolve Magento ReIndexing Errors In Magento 1.9.1 Store

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.1.0, reindex

How To Resolve Magento ReIndexing Errors In Magento 1.9.1 Store please find the below image

[image]

When I reindex product prices it is showing below error

> There was a problem with reindexing process.
>   SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: `` INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis` LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 84 AND tad_status.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 84 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1) ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 0, 1, cisi.is_in_stock), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)` ``

How to rectify this issue?

Comment: did you tried emptying var/lock folder?

Comment: lock folder is not there in my magneto var folder

Comment: Try from `shell` - `php shell/indexer.php -reindexall`

Comment: enable log and check..

Comment: as @adarsh khatri recommend, try to reindex using shell.

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with extension: Simple Configurable Products.

The indexer is trying to insert 10 values into table which have 12 columns.

[This diff shows the fix](https://github.com/obigroup/magento-configurable-simple/commit/5b62204a37ddedbeac6fd41cc39a796195810a91)

Older Magento versions didn't have products grouping and this is why SCP extension doesn't support two additional columns.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem Run this command

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` (
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
`customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group ID',
`website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID',
`tax_class_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class ID',
`orig_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Original Price',
`price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price',
`min_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Min Price',
`max_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Max Price',
`tier_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tier Price',
`base_tier` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tier',
`group_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Group price',
`base_group_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Group Price',
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`customer_group_id`,`website_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Price Indexer Final Index Table';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

in you database e.x. (phpmyadmin) this will drop the tabel and re create a new one. the problem caused be aditioanal column in you tables like store_id that you need to delete.